# Error when trying to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, servicenow, sccm

I am working to connect to a SQL server from ServiceNow. I am getting an error and I am unsure as to what it means. Any help is appreciated.

Connection URL: jdbc:sqlserver://TESTSCCMSQL01;selectMethod=cursor;databaseName=TEST_ASH;integratedSecurity=true

```
Error: java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'CAMBRIDGE\svc-p-SCCM-SN-CMDB'. ClientConnectionId:e9216fed-c737-4f09-b27b-a63f6b66b925
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:129)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1LogonProcessor.complete(SQLServerConnection.java:4786)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5068)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3731)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:94)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3675)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2488)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2142)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1993)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1164)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:760)
java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
com.service_now.mid.connections.jdbc.JDBCConnection.establishConnection(JDBCConnection.java:110)
com.service_now.mid.connections.jdbc.JDBCConnection.connect(JDBCConnection.java:82)
com.service_now.mid.connections.jdbc.JDBCConnectionFactory.create(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:65)
com.service_now.mid.connections.ConnectionCachePool.getAvailableConnection(ConnectionCachePool.java:82)
com.service_now.mid.connections.ConnectionCache.get(ConnectionCache.java:94)
com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.getJDBCConnection(JDBCProbe.java:784)
com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.probe(JDBCProbe.java:119)
com.service_now.mid.probe.AProbe.process(AProbe.java:102)
com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorker.runWorker(AWorker.java:122)
com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorkerThread.run(AWorkerThread.java:20)
com.service_now.mid.threadpool.ResourceUserQueue$RunnableProxy.run(ResourceUserQueue.java:649)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

    at com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.getJDBCConnection(JDBCProbe.java:788)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.probe(JDBCProbe.java:119)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.AProbe.process(AProbe.java:102)
    at com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorker.runWorker(AWorker.java:122)
    at com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorkerThread.run(AWorkerThread.java:20)
    at com.service_now.mid.threadpool.ResourceUserQueue$RunnableProxy.run(ResourceUserQueue.java:649)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt in the SQL Server logs? If so, what is the error there?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: Login failed for user 'CAMBRIDGE\svc-p-SCCM-SN-CMDB'. Maybe you need consult in https://serverfault.com - I'll vote to close this question because is a server related issue

Comment: The specific cause of the login failure is not returned to the client for security reasons. As, @Larnu suggested, the SQL Server error log will contain more details as to the reason. Common causes are 1) user does not have a login (server access), 2) user is not a user in the database (database access), 3) database specified in the connection string does not exist or is unavailable.

Comment: It's actually *not*, @LeandroBardelli , the authentication errors passed back to the application layer are intentionally vague. It would be bad for security if the real error was returned. For example, if "The password provided does not match the `LOGIN`'s." were returned when that was the error, then someone malicious knows that the account that they are attempt to compromise is a real account.

Comment: Oh, didn't know. Thanks! I retract my vote to close

Answer (score 0):

Is your SQL Server in 'mixed mode authentication' ? This is necessary to login with a SQL server account instead of a Windows login.

You can verify this by checking the properties of the server and then SECURITY, it should be in 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode'

This problem occurs if the user tries to log in with credentials that cannot be validated. This problem can occur in the following scenarios:

Scenario 1: The login may be a SQL Server login but the server only accepts Windows Authentication.

Scenario 2: You are trying to connect by using SQL Server Authentication but the login used does not exist on SQL Server.

Scenario 3: The login may use Windows Authentication but the login is an unrecognized Windows principal. An unrecognized Windows principal means that Windows can't verify the login. This might be because the Windows login is from an untrusted domain.

It's also possible the user put in incorrect information.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332